# Задача на пересечение отрезков, помогите закончить альтернативно (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, строки

Пересечение отрезков

На числовой прямой даны два отрезка: a1, b1, a2, b2. Напишите программу, которая находит их пересечение. Пересечением двух отрезков может быть:
отрезок;
точка;
пустое множество.
Гарантируется, что a1 < b1, a2 < b2.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести на экран границы отрезка, являющегося пересечением, либо общую точку, либо текст «пустое множество».

Sample Input 1:

```
1
3
2
4
```

Sample Output 1:

```
2 3
```

Sample Input 2:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Sample Output 2:

```
пустое множество
```

Sample Input 3:

```
5
6
6
8
```

Sample Output 3:

```
6
```

Я понимаю, как это сделать через высчитывания бесконечных возможных пересечений
Однако, мне хочется решить так:

```
a1 = int(input())
b1 = int(input())
a2 = int(input())
b2 = int(input())

line1=range(a1, b1+1)
line2=range(a2, b2+1)

l1=[]
l2=[]

for i in line1:
    l1.append(i)
for i in line2:
    l2.append(i)

for i in line1:
    for b in line2:
        if b == i == a1:
            print(b, end=' ')
        if b == i == b1:
            print(b, end=' ')
        if b == i == a2:
            print(b, end=' ')
        if b == i == b2:
            print(b, end=' ')
```

Но хоть убейте не могу вписать вариант:

```
пустое множество
```

Как в Python посчитать длину прежнего вывода - если он пустой (а через len показывает 4 символа, даже когда там вроде как ничего нету) чтобы задать условия вывода "пустого множества"

Comment: зачем все эти переборы? Вы по координатам не можете пересечение найти что ли?

Comment: могу, вопрос ведь в другом

Comment: а len чего показывает 4 символа? По идее, вам не надо проверять длины вывода, если вы можете сначала собрать строку, а потом сразу всю строку в консоль отправить.

Comment: Вот оно, спасибо. Нужно собрать например все мои b в пустой list = [] и если после выполнения перебора он все еще будет пуст - можно выводить "пустое множество"

Comment: ну да, так и производительней будет - сначала собрать результаты, потом вывести. Хотя у вас тут сложность квадрат, так что про производительность думать не приходится.

Comment: кстати, у вас в алгоритме будет неверный результат на совпадающих отрезках, типа 1-2, 1-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял, что вопрос в другом, но во избежание споров о том, что можно решить проще, накидал простой пример на C#

```
void PrintIntersection(int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2)
{
    // координаты должны быть упорядочены
    if (a1 > b1) (a1, b1) = (b1, a1);
    if (a2 > b2) (a2, b2) = (b2, a2);
    
    // первым будет отрезок с наименьшей первой координатой
    if (a1 > a2) (a1, b1, a2, b2) = (a2, b2, a1, b1);
    
    if (b1 < a2) {
        Console.WriteLine("Пустое множество");
        return;
    }
    
    if (b1 == a2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b1);
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{a2} {b1}");
}
```

Проверка

```
PrintIntersection(1, 3, 2, 4);
PrintIntersection(1, 2, 3, 4);
PrintIntersection(5, 6, 6, 8);
PrintIntersection(6, 8, 5, 6);
PrintIntersection(1, 2, 1, 2);
```

Вывод

```
2 3
Пустое множество
6
6
1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a1 = int(input())
b1 = int(input())
a2 = int(input())
b2 = int(input())

line1=range(a1, b1+1)
line2=range(a2, b2+1)

l1=[]
l2=[]
resoult=[]

for i in line1:
    l1.append(i)
for i in line2:
    l2.append(i)

for i in line1:
    for b in line2:
        if b == i == a1:
            resoult.append(b)
        if b == i == b1:
            resoult.append(b)
        if b == i == a2:
            resoult.append(b)
        if b == i == b2:
            resoult.append(b)

for i in set(resoult):   # сет убрал повторы
    print(i, end=' ')
if resoult == []:
    print('пустое множество')   # список пустой - значит совпадений нет
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# процедура сравнения отрезков
def compare_segments(line_1, line_2):
    # согласно алгоритму поиска нам надо сделать следующее:
    # сначала сравнить первые координаты отрезков и найти максимальное значение
    first_pair=max(line_1[0], line_2[0])
    # далее нам надо сравнить вторые координаты отрезков и найти минимальное
    second_pair=min(line_1[1], line_2[1])
    # теперь выполняем сравнение полученных величин
    # если первая пара меньше второй
    if first_pair < second_pair:
        # то наш результат следующий
        return(first_pair, second_pair)
    # если пары равны, то у нас пересечение это просто точка
    elif first_pair==second_pair:
        return("результат - точка; %s" % first_pair)
    # а если пара "большего" больше пары "меньшего", то
    else:
         return "пустое множество"

#точка входа в модуль
if __name__=="__main__":   
    #цикл для "бесконечной работы"
    while (True):
        line_1=[0, 0]
        line_2=[0, 0]
        # comment: просим пользователя ввести какую-нибудь строку
        text=input("Please enter first line (two digits with a space): ")
        #передаём полученную строку в метод
        # print_input_string(text)
        if text==" " or text=='':
            break
        elif len(text.split(" ")) == 2:
            line_1[0]=text.split(" ")[0]
            line_1[1]=text.split(" ")[1]
        text=input("Please enter second line (two digits with a space): ")
        if text==" " or text=='':
            break
        elif len(text.split(" ")) == 2:
            line_2[0]=text.split(" ")[0]
            line_2[1]=text.split(" ")[1]
        print(compare_segments(line_1, line_2))
      # end while
```